# Can you plot within a for loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, graph, plotly

When I try the below my plot is empty, is the below possible? With the blow code my plot is empty.

```
for (let t in test) {
            let test3 = test[t]
            const { country, deforestation_mean, fair_wages_mean, 
overall_mean, overconsumption_mean, sustainable_sourcing_mean } = test3
            

            let trace1 = [
                {
                    x: country,
                    y: deforestation_mean,
                    type: 'bar',
                },
            ];
            let trace1Layout = {
                title: 'Sustainability Metric: ' + selectedMetric.replace(/_/g, ' '),
                //margin: { t: 100 },
                hovermode: 'closest',
                xaxis: { title: 'Countries' },
                //margin: { t: 100 },
            };
            Plotly.newPlot('plot1', trace1, trace1Layout);
            console.log(country)

        }
```

I tried the below, and can successfully plot:

```
switch (selectedMetric) {
            case 'overall_mean':
                y = data.map((d) => d.overall_mean);
                break;
            case 'sustainable_sourcing_mean':
                y = data.map((d) => d.sustainable_sourcing_mean);
                break;
            case 'overconsumption_mean':
                y = data.map((d) => d.overconsumption_mean);
                break;
            case 'deforestation_mean':
                y = data.map((d) => d.deforestation_mean);
                break;
            case 'fair_wages_mean':
                y = data.map((d) => d.fair_wages_mean);
                break;
            default:
                y = data.map((d) => d.overall_mean); // Default to overall mean
        }
```

However I want to be able to plot off of different metrics.